# Is there any way to empty the "cache" in MiniZinc

Tags: caching, constraint-programming, minizinc

I'm trying to optimize a modele (in terms of the time it takes to solve). The modele returns the right answer, but MiniZinc takes too much time to find the solution.
My probleme is that, when I try to solve the modele the first time, minizinc takes its time. But when I solve the modele a second time, minizinc finds the solution almost instantly. So I can't tell if the modifications I introduced in the modele were able to accelerate the solving.
Is there a way to tell Minizinc to "forget" the solutions he found earlier.

Thank you.

Comment: How do you run the model and with what FlatZinc solver (including parameters etc)? Is it the flattening that takes time or is it the proper solving by the solver? One thing that can take time is the flattening to a FlatZinc file (.fzn). Normally that file is removed after solving but it might be used the next time.